# Is there a way to load .pf file while compiling the progress ABL code?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm new to openEdge progress 4gl.
I have only the GUI Procedure editor and app builder installed

Instead of manually connecting to the database via data administrator is there a way to load the '.pf' file for connecting to data base while compiling the code?

Answer (score 4):

Create a shortcut for the App Builder and set the -pf parameter to load the file or do it by code...

```
// On code, run the following command
CONNECT -pf c:\path...\param.pf.
```

Or by shortcut: *(Duplicate the shortcut for App Builder and add -pf)*

```
C:\Progress\bin\prowin32.exe -pf "c:\path...\param.pf" -p _ab.r
```